# I have installed ubuntu alongside Windows. Will updating Ubuntu erase data on Windows?

Tags: dual-boot

If I update Ubuntu installed in dual boot with Windows, is there any risk that the update will erase data on Windows?

Comment: Before updating make sure you have backups of both Ubuntu and Windows.  It should go smoothly and you should not lose anything in either Windows or Ubuntu but it's always better to be safe than sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Updating Ubuntu will only write to the partition(s) its already installed in.

Answer (score 1):

No, updating Ubuntu will have no affect on your Windows partition. I have done dual boots before and never has the Windows partition(s) or Ubuntu partition(s) been affected by the other OS. Update all the way